Properties of Exploding Integrals
Suppose I have a sequence of points $\{t_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ which converge to a point $t$ and a sequence functions $f_n : [0, t_n) \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ which converge pointwise to a function $f : [0, t) \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ (note that this is hypothetically possible, since for any $s <t$, for large $n$ we have $s < t_n$ so that $f_n(s)$ is well defined). Suppose further that $$\int_0^u f_n(s) ds \xrightarrow{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^u f(s)ds$$ for every $u < t$, and that $$\int_0^{t_n} f_n(s) ds = \infty$$ for every $n$. Is this enough to imply that $$\textbf{(1)} \qquad \int_0^t f(s)ds = \infty \qquad ?$$

My thoughts: I conjecture that this is true, simply because it is intuitive, and I can't come up with an example which violates this (although I am horrible at coming up with counterexamples, so I would not be surprised if there is one, and this is why I am asking). I try to proceed by contradiction and suppose that $\textbf{(1)}$ is finite. Fix any $u < t$, $\varepsilon > 0$ and note that
$$\int_0^t f(s) ds \ge \int_0^u f(s) ds \ge \int_0^u f_n(s)ds - \varepsilon $$ for all $n$ large enough. The problem comes that when we try to choose $u$ such that the right hand side is arbitrarily large, the $u$ we choose may depend on $n$, and so we do not have the desired contradiction. Even if one assumes that $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly on $[0,u]$, the same problem occurs in this proof strategy.
Any help would be massively appreciated.

Take any non-negative measurable  function $g$ on $[0,1]$ with $\int_0^{1} g(t)dt=\infty$ and $\int_0^{u}g(t)dt<\infty$ for $u<1$.[Eg. $g(t)=\frac 1 {1-t}$, for $t <1$ and $0$ for $t=1$].  Let $t_n=t=1, f_n(t)=\frac {g(t)} n$ and $f=0$.

This is a great example, thanks. Do you think there are any circumstances/additional conditions which might imply the result? If $t_n < t$ for example, I think it holds. But this is too strong of an assumption for me to make in the setting I am thinking of.
